# Present Participle or Gerund

Tags: word-usage

1."THE renowned political writer and author Seymour Hersh quot- ed verbatim an American intelligence official **telling** him the following about the recent peace summit on Ukraine hosted by the Saudi crown prince Moham- med bin Salman in Jeddah at the behest of the Biden administration:"

This is a excerpt from a news paper. Here the word "telling" is gerund or participle is really confusing to determine.

It seem to me, it is participle but sometimes gerund is also used like participle. For example

2.I hope you will excuse **my leaving** early.

3.I hope you will excuse **me leaving** early.

Above both (2 and 3) sentences "leaving " is gerund. But In first sentence I can't determine "**telling**"- whether it is gerund or participle. So please someone helps me to understand.

Comment: Consider that it can be paraphrased as “…quoted the official **as** telling him...” In the paraphrase, is *telling* a gerund or a participle?

Comment: In trad grammar "telling" is a present participle. In modern grammar it's called a gerund-participle.

Answer (score 1):

> ... Seymour Hersh quoted verbatim an American intelligence official telling him the following ...

Traditionally, there is a clear distinction between a gerund and a present participle.

As *official* is in the objective case, strictly,  *telling* is a present participle, which functions as an adjective modifying *official*.  To treat *telling* as a gerund, we need the possessive case **official's**.

In (2) "... excuse my leaving ..." and (3) "... excuse me leaving ...", the same explanation applies.  *leaving* is hence a gerund in the former and a present participle in the latter.

In modern grammar, the verb+ing form is now commonly called gerund participle.

Comment: Yes, modern grammar doesn't distinguish 'gerund' and present participle', simply referring to the _ing_ form as 'gerund-participle'. I'd say that "telling" is a verb since it has "him" as direct object. Adjectives don't take objects. Genitive case aside, nouns don't inflect for case, so "official" is best called 'plain' case. In both 2. and 3. "leaving" is a verb, not a noun